# Jackson Streaming API throws "Can not write a field name, expecting a value" error even though everything is correct

Tags: java, json, jackson, saxparser, jackson2

I am trying to convert the XML to JSON using Jackson Streaming API. The input XML file can be very large so I am using `SAX PARSER` to parse the XML and `JACKSON STREAMING API` to convert it to JSON on the go. As of now, I am using the simple example just to create basic JSON using JACKSON but it results in an error:

`com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException: Can not write a field name, expecting a value`

I am trying to call another method that will write into my JSON at the end of the particular tag which is resulting in an error. If I do not make a call to another method but write within the `endElement` method of the `SAX PARSER` then I do not get the error which I feel is a bit strange to me.

Following is my code:

```
public class JsonSaxHandler1 extends DefaultHandler {
    private JsonFactory jsonfactory = new JsonFactory();
    private StringWriter jsonObjectWriter = new StringWriter();
    private JsonGenerator jsonGenerator;
    private static JsonSaxHandler1 saxHandlerObj = null;

    public JsonSaxHandler1() throws IOException {
        jsonGenerator = jsonfactory.createGenerator(jsonObjectWriter);
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() {
        try {
            System.out.println("START");
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
            saxHandlerObj = new JsonSaxHandler1();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attribs) throws SAXException {

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("school")) {
            saxHandlerObj.createJSON();
        }
    }

    public void createJSON() {
        try {
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("country", "India");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() {

        try {
            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
            jsonGenerator.flush();
            jsonGenerator.close();
            System.out.println(jsonObjectWriter.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically `startDocument` is called at the start of the XML document. `startElement` is called at the start of the every element tag like , . `endElement` is called at the end of the every element , . `endDocument` is called at the end of the complete `XML` document.

I am trying to create the initial `JSON Object` in `startDocument` and ending it in `endDocument` but writing the values within `writeJSON` method.

If I omit the `writeJSON` method and try to write directly within the `endDocument` then everythign would work perfectly and able to get `JSON` as well:

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("school")) {
        try {
            // saxHandlerObj.createJSON();
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("country", "India");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        saxHandlerObj.createJSON();
    }
}
```

This means that the flow in which the program is going is correct and I am creating all the `JSON Object` correctly. I am getting the issue only when I try to call different methods to write my `JSON` content. I feel this should work as the call happens only once at the end of the document.

Following is my XML: (This is the sample XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<school>
    <students>
        <student>
            <name>BATMAN</name>
        </student>
    </students>
</school>
```

I would like to use the `Jackson Streaming API` and `SAX PARSER` in this application so any suggestion to solve this issue will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found out the issue. Its nothing to do with the `JACKSON` actually.
I was creating the object `saxHandlerObj` within the `startElement` which I should not do. I should create that object in the `Default Constructor` so I changed to something like this and it worked:

```
public JsonSaxHandler() throws IOException {
    jsonGenerator = jsonfactory.createGenerator(jsonObjectWriter);
    saxHandlerObj = new JsonSaxHandler();
}

@Override
public void startDocument() {
    try {
        System.out.println("START");
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```